# Echoes successful but not sending Email from a remote server

Tags: php, email-validation

```
<?php

$msg="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $from_add = "name@your-web-site.com"; 

    $to_add = "receiver@gmail.com"; //<-- I replaced this with my real gmail account

    $subject = "Test Subject";
    $message = "Test Message";

    $headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";


    if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
    {
        $msg = "Mail sent OK";
    } 
    else 
    {
       $msg = "Error sending email!";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test form to email</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $msg ?>
<p>
<form action='<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

I've got this code from http://www.html-form-guide.com, It's saying that it will check the configuration of my server if it is correctly configured to send emails.

I tried it, I uploaded it to my domain, and when I opened it, it shows the echo "Mail sent OK", but I do not receive the mail.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you checked your spam filter?  Also, did you change the "from" field to a valid email address/domain?

Comment: I don't know how to check the spam filter. Please guide me. I changed the from field.

Comment: Just look in the spam folder.

Comment: Check your spam folder in GMail

Comment: What is the actual `from` address you are using? It's not a Gmail account is it? Because Google silently discards any email that comes into it's network from the outside but looks as though it should have originated within their network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you server is setup to send mail.

What OS, mail server, are you using?

On Linux try running `sendmail` from the command line.

```
echo 'this is a test'| mail -s test_email user@somedomain.com
```

Other things to check is your mail settings in `php.ini` are correct, there is no firewall blocking outgoing mail, and that the email is not getting caught by spam filters.

Comment: And what would you do for XAMPP (*Wordpress*) on *localhost* (windows) which doesn't send mail?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $from_name ="Mahendra";
  $from_mail = "xxxx@gmail.com";
  $to = "xxxx@gmail.com";
  $subject = "Mahendra's Test Mail";
  $mail_body = "This is email test";
  $message = $mail_body ;
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
  ob_start();
  //$sendmail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

  if($sendmail)
  {
      echo "Send";
  }
  else
  {
      echo "Not Send";  
   }
```

Try this code above and I'm sure mail is sending using above code and if you will use the code above and your mail is not sending. Then 100% the problem is in your mail server. In so many projects I have used like this and its works perfectly.